# Select values in SQL that have a colum value in one row and not a specific other column value in another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

From the following table, I would like to return the set of all books that have topic 3 but do not have topic 4.

```
id  book    topic
10  1000    3
11  1000    4
12  1001    2
13  1001    3
14  1002    4
15  1003    3
```

The correct table should be:

```
book    
1001
1003
```

I made a SQL Fiddle with this for testing [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bf7a/2).

So far, I tried the following, but it returns `1000`, `1001`, `1003` (because I am not comparing two rows with each other, and do not know how to do):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM TOPICS a, TOPICS b
WHERE a.id = b.id
AND a.topic = 3 

AND NOT EXISTS (

SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM TOPICS c
WHERE a.id = c.id
AND b.topic = 4

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server (at least in the fiddle) you could use the `except`set operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT book FROM TOPICS WHERE topic = 3 
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT book FROM TOPICS WHERE topic = 4
```

This would return 1001 and 1003.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. The `not exists` condition is definitely the right idea, you just need to apply another one of these for checking the existence of topic 3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.book
FROM   topics a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   topics b
               WHERE  a.book = b.book AND b.topic = 3) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM   topics b
                  WHERE  a.book = b.book AND b.topic = 4)
```

Comment: @jpw arg, indeed. Wasn't paying attention there. Fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

Using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT a.book
FROM TOPICS a
WHERE a.topic = 3 
   AND NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1
    FROM TOPICS b
    WHERE a.book = b.book
    AND b.topic = 4)
```